# The significance of Basis functions in contructing a BSpline Curve

Tags: numerical-methods, curves, spline

I am new to B-Spline and have some doubts in the basic concepts. I am trying to understand the involvement of the Basis function in the formation of the curve. How is it involved in the construction of the curve. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D parametric curve is a linear combination of the control points, where the coefficients are the basis functions. The role of the b-spline basis functions is exactly analogous to the role of Bernstein polynomials in the construction of Bézier curves.